# How to view histograms juxtaposed using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize how the distributions differ based on the flag column:

Sample Data:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : np.random.uniform(size = 100),
                  'col2' : np.random.uniform(size = 100),
                  'col3' : np.random.uniform(size = 100),
                  'flag' : np.random.choice([0,1], 100)})
df
    col1        col2        col3        flag
0   0.548814    0.677817    0.311796    0
1   0.715189    0.270008    0.696343    0
2   0.602763    0.735194    0.377752    1
3   0.544883    0.962189    0.179604    1
4   0.423655    0.248753    0.024679    1
... ... ... ... ...
95  0.183191    0.490459    0.224317    0
96  0.586513    0.227415    0.097844    0
97  0.020108    0.254356    0.862192    0
98  0.828940    0.058029    0.972919    1
99  0.004695    0.434417    0.960835    0
```

I can view the histograms using 2 `for` loops one each for `flag == 0` and `flag == 1` using:

```
for col in df.loc[df['flag'] == 0, ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].columns:
    plt.hist(df[col])
    plt.title(col)
    plt.show()
```

Could someone please let me know if I can generate visualizations wherein the histograms for each column is placed side by side, one each for different `flag` columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) is well suited for this:

```
import seaborn as sns
...
sns.displot(df.melt(id_vars='flag'), row='variable', col='flag', x='value')
```

Output:

[image]